# Android listview layout does not fit my expect

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm using Listview to show the search result ,but why it doesn't fit my parent view?I want to make it fill the rest Linearlayout zoom,Please help me,thanks.

xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_et"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:hint="输入要查找的内容" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="搜索"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: reality layout view,Listview could scroll and it doesn't fill the rest zoom]

Comment: Try changing the ScrollView to a LinearLayout.  I don't know if that's the problem, but it's a bad thing to put a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: appreciate your advice,let me had a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `ListView` within a `ScrollView`.

Quoting docs

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

If you use `LinearLayout` use weights for `LinearLayout` and `ListView`.

You can use a `RelativeLayout`. There is no need for a `ScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ll"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_et"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:hint="输入要查找的内容" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="搜索"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll"            
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </ListView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: you're right,could mind post the links of your quoting docs for me ?I should learn more about ui

Comment: @Bruce use a `RelativeLayout`. check the post

Comment: @Bruce by the way i don't see the need for a scrollview in your case.

Comment: I fix it.well,I mean I want the Quoting docs,where did you get that?

Answer (score 0):

remove the scrollview from the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_et"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="输入要查找的内容"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="搜索" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```